# Bound for the sum of a finite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

Consider ${\bf c} = (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $0< \|{\bf c}\| < 1.$ Let $n \in \mathbb{N} $ and define 
\begin{align*}
F_{n}(k) & := \frac{ [a + x_{n}(k)]^2}{ [a + x_{n}(k)]^2 + [b + y_{n}(k)]^2}
\end{align*}
where $\omega := 2\pi/n,$  $x_{n}(k) := \cos(2 k \pi/n)$ and $y_{n}(k) := \sin(2 k \pi/n).$
The question is to find an upper bound $h = h(n,{\bf c})$ on the sum $S_n$ 
such that 
$$ S_n \leq h(n,{\bf c}),$$
where
$$S_n =\left( \frac{2 \pi}{n}\right) \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} F_{n}(k).$$
Is there any result that can help to find such a bound ?

Comment: Surely you are not looking for this but one trivial upper bound is $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is the following:

Let $z_k=x_n(k)+iy_n(k)=e^{ik\omega}$ and $c=a+ib=re^{i\theta}$ with $0<r<1$. Then, $F_n(k)=\cos^2\theta_k,\ 0\le k\le n-1$ where $\theta_k=\angle (z_k+c)$ so that $F_n(k)=\pi+\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos 2\theta_k$.

I think this can be helpful in finding some bounds.

**Edit:** One can note that $\tan\theta_k=\frac{r\sin \theta+\sin k\omega}{r\cos \theta+\cos k\omega}$. Then, $$\cos2\theta_k=\frac{1-\tan^2{\theta_k}}{1+\tan^2\theta_k}=\frac{r^2\cos 2\theta+2r\cos(\theta+k\omega)+\cos2k\omega}{r^2+1+2r\cos(\theta-k\omega)}$$ So, $$S_n=\pi+\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{r^2\cos2\theta+2r\cos(\theta+k\omega)+\cos2k\omega}{r^2+1+2r\cos(\theta-k\omega)}=\pi+\frac{\pi}{n}(A\cdot r^2\cos2\theta+B+C)$$

Now, we can write $$A=\frac{1}{r^2+1+2r\cos(\theta-k\omega)}=\frac{1}{r^2+1}\left(1-a\cos(\theta-k\omega)+a^2\cos^2(\theta-k\omega)+\cdots\right),\ a=\frac{2r}{r^2+1}\\=\frac{1}{r^2+1}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}(-1)^la^l\cos^l(\theta-k\omega)\\=\frac{1}{r^2+1}\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor l/2\rfloor}\frac{a^l}{2^l}\binom{l}{2m}\cos((l-2m)(\theta-k\omega))$$ So that $$A=\frac{1}{r^2+1}\sum_{l\ge 0}\left(\frac{a^2}{4}\right)^{l}\binom{2l}{l}\\=\frac{1}{r^2+1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(xC(x)\right)\mid_{x=a^2/4}$$ where $C(x)$ is the generating function of [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). Hence $\displaystyle xC(x)=(1-\sqrt{1-4x})/2\implies A=\frac{1}{(r^2+1)\sqrt{1-a^2}}=\frac{1}{1-r^2}$ With similar manipulation one can attempt to find exact expressions for $B,C$ and can find a suitable upper bound of $S_n$, though I guess those exact expressions will not be easy to handle.

Comment: Thanks Samrat. I think $\theta_{k} = \angle (z_k + c).$ This suggest that bound is independent of $c.$

Comment: There is still a catch. I can imagine $\cos(2\theta_k)$ as real part of $e^{2 i \theta_k}$ and this is not a geometric series. Is there any bound for such a sequence ?

Comment: Oops! Sorry @NaveenCrasta, I am correcting that.

Comment: @NaveenCrasta, I have made some edits which may be used to find a legible upper bound.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was searching for this type of problem. Eventually it lead to something called Weyl sum and it goes on from there.

Comment: The last equality $$a_k - b_k = -\sin\left(\frac{ 3k\omega+\theta }{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{ k\omega-\theta }{2}\right)$$ which follows from $$ \cos(A)-\cos(B) = -2 \sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right).$$

Comment: @NaveenCrasta, I know the last equality but did not write because I do not think it is going to help. BTW thank you for the information about Weyl sum. Also, I think what I wrote in the edit is not totally correct, I am going to make a further edit to set things correct.

Comment: Thanks @Samrat. Here is something that I was thinking. Define                \begin{align*}
A_{n}(k) & := \frac{ [a + x_{n}(k)] }{\sqrt{  [a + x_{n}(k)]^2 + [b + y_{n}(k)]^2}},\\
B_{n}(k) & := \frac{ [b + y_{n}(k)]}{\sqrt{ [a + x_{n}(k)]^2 + [b + y_{n}(k)]^2}}.\end{align*} Consider  \begin{align*}                                                                                          {\bar S}_n & =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (A_{n}(k) + i B_{n}(k) )^{2} =  \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^{2 i \theta_k}.                                                                                                  \end{align*}

Comment: @NaveenCrasta, but what you have written is entirely different from what you defined $S_n$ to be. Look at my new edit, probably you'll get some idea how to find an upper bound for the sum.

Comment: I agree with you but that can be recovered easily as the real part of $\bar{S}_n$ which has two terms and they are sin and cosines.

Comment: Ok, so do you want to upper bound $\overline{S_n}$? Since $\overline{S_n}$ is a complex quantity you cannot have a bound on that, you can only find, if possible, its exact value. Otherwise you have to probably go along the lines I went to find $S_n$. Though it is not easy, but it will do the job.

Comment: @ Samrat: I was thinking that I can get $S_n$ from $\bar{S}_n$ (as real part) but it is not correct.